# Azure Service Bus Queue Using Subscriptions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-queues

I am trying to use subscription in Azure Service Bus queue, however I get the following error message:

> Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: The messaging entity
> 'local-test-manual:Queue:exports|4240a9fa-9fb0-43e5-b506-d2bc593aee5e'
> could not be found. To know more visit
> https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.

**Service Bus Namespace:** local-test-manual

**Queue name:** exports

Getting the same error when running a sample from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions (for using subscriptionName)

[image]

When I remove the subscription name it works fine. However, I do need to use a subscription as I'm using the same queue for different instances of my app.

Do sessions need to be enabled for Subscriptions to work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-message-sessions

Not sure what else to try

Comment: I think it has to do with the Service Bus fully qualified Namespace name. Check your image, could just be a typo.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I needed to create "TOPICS" and "SUBSCRPTION". Not QUEUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of creating a 'queue', I had to create a Topic and Subscription within a topic:
[image]